# Sent Ether does not reach recipient on Testnet (Morden)

Tags: transactions, wallets, mist, ether, testnets

I'm trying to send Ether from an account of mine to a friend's account. I'm using the Ethereum Wallet application on Windows, my friend uses the Ethereum Wallet application on a Linux VM. The network seems to recognize the recipient account. When I send Ether to that account, transaction is completed on my side, but my friend never receives the Ether.
Do you have any idea what could be the problem ?

Note: sending Ether from my account to another account of mine works well.

Thanks

Comment: Do you have transaction number? If so, you can check it against a blockchain explorer.  Was your account actually decremented by the amount you sent?

Comment: I actually have the same problem. I was "seemingly" successful in mining a decent number of Ethers, but when I actually sent my Ethers to another wallet, it was never received. The transaction posted that it was confirmed 50+, but the balance never showed up in both my Quione Exchange account or my Other wallet in Ethereum wallet in the Main Network. However, my balance in the Testnet (Morden) account has already decreased. Please advise. Thanks Eth Wallet: 0x083fa7e3db6a4fc8ae2586cf77c959e90c8c07ed

Comment: Can you post your TX id? You can actually check if your TX is successful in testnet.etherscan.io

Comment: My Trx ID: 73a002c69a850ffeb2b947852dd5f8fb753b16cf92d It also shows that it was already confirmed by 315 blocks on Etherscan.io Any idea what went on here?

Comment: Its probably because your friend has not synced with the latest testnet chain yet. Can you ask him to check which block is he in right now?

Comment: thanks for your replies. It actually now works. It was just something to do with network proxy that did not allow some protocoles. But the problem is solved :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that I was using an internal network from my compagny (with some proxy limitations). I just switched to an external network and it worked. I haven't been looking more deepely into the issue so far.